# How to sort a multi-dimensional array by values which are dates?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am struggling with this. Sorting a multi-dimensional array by value based on dates. Here is a snippet of the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [clicks] => 14
            [point] => 11 February 2011
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [clicks] => 1
            [point] => 14 February 2011
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [clicks] => 8
            [point] => 15 February 2011
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [clicks] => 0
            [point] => 08 February 2011
        )
```

I would like to sort it by date with the keys in the correct order. So in this case the `08 February 2011` should get key `0`. I tried to make use of usort but that didn't go well as I couldn't even make use of the callback function in codeigniter which is another problem I am researching.

What is the most efficient way of doing this? My array can grow to 60 entries.

Thanks all for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This custom sort should work:

```
function cmp($a, $b){
    $l = strtotime($a['point']);
    $r = strtotime($b['point']);
    if($l == $r){
        return 0;
    }
    return $l < $r ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arr, "cmp");
```

Comment: Both functions work but I have gone for this as it tests if they are equal. I am not sure if Tim's answer accounts for this, but I understand this function more easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, **$data** is your multi-dimensional array.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $point[$key]  = strtotime($row['point']);
}

// Sort the data with date ascending
array_multisort($point, SORT_ASC, $data);
```

See **array_multisort** function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php (very useful for sorting multi-dimensional arrays)

Hope this helps.